# How can I get all users that my bot can see?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So I’m having issues with something and I’m unsure if I need an intent. Sometimes it works other times it doesn’t. But, when I try to get all my members using `client.guilds.cache.reduce((a, g) filter => a + g.memberCount, 0)` and I get NaN back. Any way around this that won’t affect my bot possibly or even make it faster?

Comment: `client.users.cache.size` - If it's empty, or just your bot is in it, you need an intent.

Comment: What intent do I need? Because I want to be able to collect everyone. Is it guild_members or something?

Comment: GUILD_MEMBERS (SERVER MEMBERS INTENT)

Comment: Ah thank you. I’ll see what I can do then.